# Split some Excel rows to new columns

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have an Excel file that contains more than 500 rows of data under three columns (columns A-C). Based on column A's value, I would like to move some rows from columns A-C to new three columns. Is there any formula to do that?

Before

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 51 | 81 |
| 1 | 61 | 91 |
| 2 | 52 | 82 |
| 2 | 72 | 92 |
| 3 | 53 | 83 |
| 3 | 73 | 93 |

After

| A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 51 | 81 | 2 | 52 | 82 | 3 | 53 | 83 |
| 1 | 61 | 91 | 2 | 72 | 92 | 3 | 73 | 93 |

Thank you.

Comment: That could be done easily with VBA. Please show us what you've tried so we can help you fix it (hint: try something yourself before posting here).

Comment: Please provide more details about how would be the expansion to more rows in the input, so we can understand how would be the output. We provided several answer here for your input data, but how would be the output for the case of more rows in the input is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: It being a challenging question with many discussions on how it should be interpreted, it would be nice to pick an answer from (the many very good) answers by ticking the `v` mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Would the follow do?

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,{1,2,3},LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(A:C,A:A=y)))),,1)
```

Comment: Nice one. If it's not actual 1 2 3 : `=DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(TOROW(A:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(A:C,A:A=y)))),,1)`

Comment: @P.b revised : `=DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TAKE(DROP(A:C,1),,1),1)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(A:C,A:A=y)))),,1)`

Comment: I used to row instead of tocol `=DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(A:C,A:A=y)))),,1)`

Comment: concise solution @JvDv, just a quick comment, adding two more rows will require to replace `{1,2,3}` with `{1,2,3,4}` and so on, or `SEQUENCE(ROWS(TOCOL(A:A,1))/2)`for the general case.

Comment: @DavidLeal, thanks for the feedback, much appreciated. My understanding of the question is that all 500 rows (and potential future ones) will fall under one of three possible categories found in the 1st column (hence the six columns needed). No more, no less. I don't think OP meant to expand more categories thus over six columns wide. Hardcoding `{1,2,3}` was for me a shortcut to deal with the given sample data, but could be transformed quite easily to capture these three unique values to begin with. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV maybe we have a different interpretation of the question. When more rows are added, then more columns will be added, per my understanding in the final result. If the intention is to organize the output by odd rows, then even rows. If you don't do that in your formula adding two more rows, will not appear in the result for rows starting with `4` number for example, for an existing number, returns an error. How would be the expansion to more rows under your approach? Maybe I am missing something here. Thanks! Not clear from the question how would be the expansion understood.

Comment: Yeah it's a different understanding. As mentioned, all 500 rows (in my interpretation) will have either a 1, a 2 or a 3 in the 1st column (or to be more concise: the option out of three categories in total).  Add another row, chuck a 1 in the 1st column to see what I mean. The answer could be improved with a nested `IFERROR()`, in the event the count of rows for each of the three categories won't even out. @DavidLeal. It's clear to me that other answers take different starting points. It just so happen that the basis of my answer caters for both with some tweaks apparently.

Comment: I see @JvdV your interpretation is that for more rows, in the input means more rows in the output with fix number of columns and mine the same number of rows in the output but more columns. Lets see what the OP has to say about the real scenario. With limited input data it is difficult to be sure about which real scenario is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### HStack Every Other Row

[image]

**Formula**

```
=LET(table,A1:C10,we,"",
    h,TAKE(table,1),d,DROP(table,1),
    r,ROWS(d),c,COLUMNS(d),
    rr,INT((r+1)/2),tc,rr*c,
    rh,INDEX(h,MOD(SEQUENCE(,tc)-1,c)+1),
    rs,VSTACK(SEQUENCE(rr,,,2),SEQUENCE(r-rr,,2,2)),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,c),
    rd,WRAPROWS(TOROW(INDEX(d,rs,cs)),tc,we),
VSTACK(rh,rd))
```

- If you want to hide the zeros, you can always replace `rd` with `IF(rd=0,"",rd)` in the last line. This is especially useful if the values are not numbers.

**Variables**

```
table - the table range
we    - wrap error - what to return if an odd number of data rows
h     - headers
d     - data
r     - number of data rows
c     - number of columns
rr    - about half (e.g. 4 for 7) of the data rows
tc    - number of total resulting columns
rh    - resulting headers
rs    - resulting data row sequence
cs    - resulting data column sequence
rd    - resulting data
```

**Edit**

- Credits to David Leal: to simplify, the `INDEX` expression could be replaced with a `CHOOSEROWS` expression making the `cs` variable redundant:

  - remove the line `cs,SEQUENCE(,c),`
  - replace `INDEX(d,rs,cs)` with `CHOOSEROWS(d,rs)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here another approach not using [Lambda helper functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648), based on the pattern shown in the input data, i.e. we want to stack horizontally odd rows and then even rows. If more rows are added in the input, the result will be 2-rows with more columns adding the corresponding additional rows.

*More clarification from the question would be needed to understand how would be the expansion to more rows*.

```
=LET(in,A2:C7, n,ROWS(in)/2, seq,SEQUENCE(n,,,2),
 WRAPROWS(TOCOL(VSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(in,seq), 
  CHOOSEROWS(in,seq+1))), n*COLUMNS(in)))
```

**Note**: If you prefer to use as a reference the entire column (usually less efficient), then set the value for `in` as follows: `DROP(FILTER(A:C,A:A<>""),1)`.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We use `CHOOSECOLS` to select even and odd rows from the input data (`in`), then stack the result vertically via `VSTACK` and convert it to a single column via `TOCOL`. Finally, use `WRAPROWS` to wrap the output of `TOCOL` to the desired output.

If you want to include the header:

```
=LET(in,A2:C9, n,ROWS(in)/2, seq,SEQUENCE(n,,,2), m,COLUMNS(in), nm,n*m, 
 h,INDEX(A1:C1,MOD(SEQUENCE(,nm,0),m)+1),
 VSTACK(h,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(VSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(in,seq),
  CHOOSEROWS(in, seq+1))), nm)))
```

In the above formula we build the header (`h`), using `INDEX` and the sequence: `MOD(SEQUENCE(,nm,0),n)+1)` which generates the sequence: `1,2,3,1,2,3,...`. The header can also be built using the following:

```
TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(,n),TOCOL(A1:C1)),,1)
```

Comment: Great! I knew there had to be something like that but I couldn't figure it out in quite a few attempts. Now I see that I got pretty close but just couldn't get the order of the functions right.

Comment: yes, thanks @VBasic2008 your solution was in that direction too, using `WRAPROWS`. Now that I am looking to it in more details. I used `CHOOSEROWS` to simplify the process.

Comment: My goal was to do `VSTACK(h, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(?),?))` with the 1st question mark a little less complicated.

Comment: Probably there is a shorter way to generate the header, but I was not able to find it, so I leave it like that using `MOD`.

Comment: I found it: `TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(in)),TOCOL(A1:C1)),,1)` but it is not shorter, or not, because `COLUMNS(in) = n` in my formula.

Comment: I see you used the 3rd parameter `0` while I didn't but had to do `-1`. Totally forgot about it. It will reduce two characters (the parentheses) when using the `INT` version to get e.g. `1,1,1,2,2,2,...`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (Without using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper)

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(
       a,DROP(FILTER(A:C,A:A<>""),1),
       b,COLUMNS(a),
       c,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
       d,TOROW(SEQUENCE(,b)+TOCOL(FILTER(c,ISODD(c))-{1,0},,1)*b),
       e,WRAPROWS(d,ROWS(UNIQUE(TAKE(a,,1)))*b),
       INDEX(TOCOL(a),e)
       )
```

---

[image]

---

**With Headers:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(
       a,DROP(FILTER(A:C,A:A<>""),1),
       b,COLUMNS(a),
       c,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
       d,TOROW(SEQUENCE(,b)+TOCOL(FILTER(c,ISODD(c))-{1,0},,1)*b),
       e,ROWS(UNIQUE(TAKE(a,,1))),
       f,WRAPROWS(d,e*b),
       g,TEXTSPLIT(REPT(TEXTJOIN("|",,A1:C1)&"|",e),"|",,1),
       VSTACK(g,INDEX(TOCOL(a),f))
       )
```

---

[image]

---